# Oracle Application Express Dev Environment

Tags: oracle-apex

When developing with application express, I am struggling with how to implement version control and how to have both DEV and PROD versions of an application.  How do you publish changes from dev to prod?  I know that I can export the entire application and then import into production, but is there a way to just import changes easily?

APEX 3.2 on Oracle 10g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For our Apex Applications* we have adopted the export\import method at the apex application level. Can be bit of an overkill for small changes but it works.

This [thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=3723807&#3723807) on the Apex OTN forum seems to point to application level exports for version control as well.

*Just to clarify where I say Apex application what I mean is the sql file that Apex produces on an export.